# Portable Device Type that is connected

Tags: c#, android, windows, mobile, wmi

When a smart phone is connected to a computer, how to determine from the computer that the newly connected device is a smart phone, and not an external drive or some other portable devices like camera.

May be,  I guess I can get for IMEI number to uniquely identify it as some phone variety, but I am not able figure an approach.

Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: How did you connect the device to the computer?

Comment: i am not specific to any particular type of connection. I like to know if there is a soln for this.Any type of connection works for me. Say with "USB Cable" as "Mass Storage", or through bluetooth.